# multi select not work in ng-repate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using ultraselect Jquery, I want to select multiple options but the one which  I did,doesn't work.May I know where is the issue?

**Codes:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Options displayed in comma-separated list
        $(".control_7").ultraselect({oneOrMoreSelected: '*'})

    });

</script>



<!-- Main content -->
<div  ng-repeat="salon in salons">  <!-- dir-paginate="salon in salons| itemsPerPage: 1"-->

    <select class="control_7" name="control_7[]" multiple >
        <option >Option 1</option>
        <option >Option 2</option>
        <option >Option 3</option>
        <option >Option 4</option>
        <option >Option 5</option>
        <option >Option 6</option>
        <option >Option 7</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: you should try to keep jquery from angularjs, i suggest you take a look at [Ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) for a multi-select plugin in angularjs,.

Comment: The only thing you can do is creating a directive to handle the jQuery plugin. Otherwise AngularJS and jQuery will work for their own...